# nltk how convert my dataset to specific format

Tags: python, nltk

I have a dataset in form of smsspamcollection. I'm gonna classify it in order to detect Sms Spam messages. 
first of all i need to convert my dataset structure to something like nltk.corpus.movie_reviews dataset and Then, by using NaivebayesClassifier, I classify the data and get accuracy .
How can I convert dataset . any idea?

Comment: Please read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve]